# Translate "Dynamic" and "Flexibility" in a programming context

Tags: adverb, pronominal-adverb

I want to speak about the "dynamic" capabilities of a programming language to my german team.  With "dynamic" capabilities, I mean the capacity of a language to handle complex objects and processes, as explained in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language). I would first translate it by "Dynamischkeit" but this doesn't seem clean to me (German is not my mother tong).

Then, I would also like to talk about the "flexibility" of a programming language. By flexibility, I mean the ease of a programming language to pass from some objects to others. This [Question](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-most-flexible-programming-languages-in-your-opinion) mentions "The ability to change something in a smart way that lead to radical and useful changes in results". Here, I would talk about "Flexibilität", but again I'm not sure if it's the most appropriate.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us start with "flexibility", because this is easier: *Flexibilität* is exactly the word you look for. The english as well as the german word come from the latin verb "flectere", which means "to bend". Words like "circumflex" (bent around in a circle), "flexion" (modification of a word for declination/conjugation) etc. also come from this word and are used in English and in German as well.

The noun associated with the *Adjektiv*/*Adverb* "dynamisch" is *Dynamik*, but that rather means the quality itself. Here are a few words related to "Dynamik":

> *Dynamik* (noun, the quality itself - dynamic[s])

> *dynamisch* (adjective/adverb - dynamic)

> *dynamisieren* (verb - to make sth. dynamic)

> [ *Dynamizität* (noun, - the extent to which sth. has the quality) ]

I'd rather not use the last one, even if correct - that might sound a bit over the top.

Comment: Ok, vielen dank. Damit kann ich vorwärts gehen